# Error While generating java classes from WSDL using wsimport

Tags: jax-ws

I am developing web service using `JAX-WS`. After Publishing the web service when I tried to generate client stubs using wsimport I have found following issue.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vberi\prac_workspace_27_05_2013\WS-Client\src>wsimport
 -s . http://ntlnvn.bmb.com:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl
```

parsing WSDL...

```
[ERROR] file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/vberi/prac_workspace_27_05_2013/WS-C
lient/src/ûs
```

is unreachable

```
    Failed to parse the `WSDL`.
```

**I am able to open wsdl through http://mtlnvn.bmb.com:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl****

Answer (score 2):

Try out the below steps:

1. Go to the wsdl file http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL
2. Right click save as (saving it to your local system), give some name say `geoipservice` (save type will be xml document by default, so don't save as `geoipservice.xml` again)
3. Now type `wsimport geoipservice.xml` in cmd, you will get the generated class.

Comment: sometime you'll need to repeat the same way for the xsd dependencies. For  example, you will have to save http://localhost:8080/myApi?xsd=1 as a local xsd file and adapt parent xml "import" element: (attribute "location") to the xsd file name instead of localhost url..

Answer (score 1):

Being new to developing Webservices using JAX-WS, I was facing a similar issue, and was following this [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world)

The solution you can try is:-

**o** As said in one of the answers, correct the url, between `ntlnvn` and `mtlnvn`

**o** Make sure the project name should not contain `spaces` or special characters like `- _ .` , don't know the exact reason for it, but renaming the project has worked for me once. Maybe the `wsimport` command has problem dealing with spaces and special characters .

**o** Most important, which worked for me is that change the build command to:-

`wsimport -keep http://mtlnvn.bmb.com:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl`

Answer (score 1):

I am working on the same tutorial and faced with the same problem.
Did everything suggested in these answers.

What worked for me was removing the "**-s .**" part from the wsimport command.

When i ran the

**`wsimport  http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl`** command, all the files got created without an issue.

Hope this will work for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the link provided is only accessible inside your network.

I believe the problem might be a typo. ntlnvn against mtlnvn. First letter is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the steps I made:

1.- To make sure that your connection is ok and the web service is available: Open the wsdl in a browser (as you did). Also you can test it with curl.

2.- To make sure that your configuration is all ok: You can test wsimport with another url, for example: wsimport -d C:\deleteFolder -verbose -B-XautoNameResolution  http://www.xmlme.com/WSAmazonBox.asmx?WSDL

My concrete problem was that I was using a host name (file hosts from windows). I changed the name for the IP and I had another different problem (failed to read the WSDL document). 
Perhaps it could help.

Another test i did was to shutdown the server. I was a bit shocked when I realized that the error was the same! ([...] is unreachable, failed to parse the wsdl).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution is to remove all spaces from your project path. After the change it worked well.

In your case the path should be:

```
    C:\Documents_and_Settings\vberi\prac_workspace_27_05_2013\WS- Client\src>wsimport...
```

Of course it can not be then you must change a project path.

[Problem is mentoined here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=241246)